# Creating two div columns on the sides of the site

Tags: html, css

The black bars are supposed to hug the edge of the page, "designed" the bars in a HTML/CSS phone app and they alligned at the edge perfectly. ( NOTE the length is temporary)

[image]

```
<div id="leftcolumn"></div>
<div class="middlecontent" align="left">Middle content</div>
<div id="rightcolumn"></div>
```

Stylesheet

```
.middlecontent {
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-top: 15%;
    height: 200px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    display: inline;

}   
#leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #11151C;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;

}
#rightcolumn {
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #11151C;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;

}
```

Comment: You can't use `float` and `display:inline` at the same time. What **exactly** is your question?

Comment: i gotta edit this, the black bars are supposed two be at the left and the right side but the right one is leaving a little gap between it and the edge

Comment: Then you need to demo the issue.

Comment: You should not be using `display: inline;` at all for this layout. Just go ahead and remove it from your code completely.

Comment: Tyler, how can i get the columns in-line then?

Comment: @Paulie_D you just remind me an ancient workaround: in IE6 float and display: inline were both necessary to prevent the double margin bug. :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments already, you can't use `display: inline` and `float` at the same time.

And moreover `box-sizing: content-box` is already the default box-sizing, which is useless unless you specify the width.

The `float: right` always skips to a newline if there is not enough space to occupy in the row.

I would suggest `display: flex` instead.

And try to slim your code.

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}

#leftcolumn, #rightcolumn {
    height: 200px;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #11151C;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#rightcolumn{
  margin-left:auto;
}
.middlecontent{
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-top: 15%;
    height: 200px;
}
/*.middlecontent {
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-top: 15%;
    height: 200px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    display: inline;

}   
#leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #11151C;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;

}
#rightcolumn {
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #11151C;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;

}*/
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div id="leftcolumn"></div>
<div class="middlecontent" align="left">Middle content</div>
<div id="rightcolumn"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: usually i compile and tidy up the code in the end. This isnt working either, it just places the two "bars" on top of each other and not on the opposing sides

Comment: sorry. Please see the edited code. `margin-left: auto` on the right element does the trick.

Comment: still, they're not on the same lines mirroring each other but the right one is under the left one but on the other side

Comment: It's impossible. `display: flex` is meant to stay on the same line. Can you post the whole code of yours?

Comment: ok this is weird, the code you submitted doesnt work in Dreamweaver neither in design or live view, but when i uploaded the site it works fine in browser

Comment: Maybe your browser is caching the stylesheet. Turn off cache mode during development.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CSS grid.  I wrapped your HTML in a div with the class grid.  and removed the margins from the class and used grid for that.  Also, removed the floats and display: inline.  I noticed you used margin-top: 15% and perhaps you have a reason but I just gave the top auto so it fits the size of your content. Finally, I adding margin: auto 0; to the body to prevent margins on the body itself.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="top">content</div>
  <div id="leftcolumn"></div>
  <div class="middlecontent" align="left">Middle content</div>
  <div id="rightcolumn"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% auto 15%;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}
.top {
  background: pink;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.middlecontent {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2;
  height: 200px;
}   
#leftcolumn {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #11151C;
}
#rightcolumn {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 2;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #11151C
}
```